# Why border-top doesn't give same border width while using display:table in div area?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML file: **index.html**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
.div_table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.div_table_row {
  display: table-row;
}

.div_table_header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.div_table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 11px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test tera</title>
  <meta name="Tera_tutorial" content="Tera tutorial">
  <meta name="author" content="Practice">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src=""></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="div_table">
    <!-- Table header -->
    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>First name</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>Last name</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>Email</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Users table content -->

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-01.lname-01@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-02.lname-02@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-03</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-03</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-03.lname-03@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

If I open my HTML file in Firefox everything works as expected and I see above each row (the border-top I mean) a black thin border (1px). However if I open the same file with Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Brave, etc. I can see that the first and 3rd row have ticker upper borders.

Can you please explain where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance

[EDIT]:
Here is what I see in Firefox
[image]

But here is the different result (look at the 1st and 3rd row) in Google Chrome
[image]

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing. But, I'm getting 1px dark top border on all devices. You can use the dev tool if you're confused.

Comment: Just a guess, but because the snippet I added for you doesn't do what you describe. I would imagine you have some conflicting styles. Please add an [example].

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but why are you using divs and doing `display: table;` ect? You clearly want it to be a table so use the html element table. You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics). "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck" = use the table.

Comment: @Mehdi Hasan I just added to pictures to the post showing the difference.

Comment: @DEjan.S Actually, until a while ago I didn't even know display: table using div. I'm not an expert in HTML. One of my colleagues who develops a lot of Web sites, once told me that since HTML5 and more generally since mobile development it's not good to use <table> element anymore as it's not flexible on different devices and responsive. He told me that the combination of div and display:table is the correct way to go for tabulars and to forget about <table> element once for all. Given that I wasn't/am not an expert in the field I didn't really seek to argue with him. Did I make a mistake?  :)

Comment: Yes tables aren't as responsive as other elements, but and a big BUT, using a div with `display: table;` does not change any responsive behaviour because you are telling it to act like a table, so ask "how does a div + display table change the responsiveness?". Let's touch on accessibility for a second and how not having the right semantics will effect that, like are you using aria on your divs? Because using `<table>`will do that automatically. I recommend reading [this excellent article](https://adrianroselli.com/2018/05/functions-to-add-aria-to-tables-and-lists.html) and watching the videos

Comment: I recommend to read about EU enforcing laws regarding accessibility for Ecommerce sites (actually this July). I guess depending on the country but many has already that state actor sites has to be accessible. If we put aside the laws, you should develop a site so a person with a disability should be able to use it, it could be anything from color blindness or a person that can't use a mouse/keyboard. Keep that in mind :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually recently I've found a free open source screen reader : https://www.nvaccess.org/   Even where I'm working there has been significant attention to the question of accessibility recently. And the colleague whom I talked above, advocated the idea that display:table is much more screen reader friendly than <table>. Searching a bit on google apparently there are some heated debated on this subject :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `border-collapse` property that you set on your `.div_table` class.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
.div_table {
  display: table;
}

.div_table_row {
  display: table-row;
}

.div_table_header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.div_table_cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 11px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test tera</title>
  <meta name="Tera_tutorial" content="Tera tutorial">
  <meta name="author" content="Practice">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src=""></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="div_table">
    <!-- Table header -->
    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>First name</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>Last name</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell div_table_header">
        <p>Email</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Users table content -->

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-01.lname-01@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-02.lname-02@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-03</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>lname-03</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_table_cell">
        <p>fname-03.lname-03@mycorporate.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. But at the same time I'm a bit confused because the collapse property as far know is recognized by most of widely used browsers and allows to remove any undesired space between borders. So why this causes the problem?